# How to use the value of two variables from one class in another in C++

Tags: c++

So I want to be able to use the values of `x` and `y` in the class `extra` and set them equal to `z` and `w`.

I can't seem to figure out why it's not working.

I've been trying to use the friend class, but it's not working.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class extra;
class Regner
{
 friend class extra;

 public:

 void getInput();
 void calculate();

 private:

 double x;
 double y;
};

class extra
{
 public:

 extra ():z(0),w(0){}

 void bruger()
 {
    Regner one;
    z = one.x;
    w = one.y;
 }

 //void udfrabruger(){
    //cout<<"z/w = "<<z/w<<endl;
 //}

 private:

 double z, w;
};

int main()
{
 Regner find;          // construct a default object
 extra find2;
 find.getInput();      // ask for user input
 find.calculate();     // use it
 find2.bruger();
 //  find2.udfrabruger();
}

void Regner::getInput()
{
 cout << "Enter x: ";
 cin >> x;
 cout << "Enter y: ";
 cin >> y;
}

void Regner::calculate()
{
 cout << "x + y = " << x + y << endl;
 cout << "x - y = " << x - y << endl;
 cout << "x * y = " << x * y << endl;
}
```

Comment: What exactly _doesn't work_? You are aware that  `Regner one;` in `bruger()` and `Regner find;` in `main()` are completely unrelated instances, are you?

Answer (score 1):

`find` and `find2` are unrelated until you make them related.

Change the `bruger` function to pass the `Regner` object as argument, rather than creating a local copy:

```
void bruger(Regner one)
{
    z = one.x;
    w = one.y;
}
```

Then, call it in `main` as:

```
find2.bruger(find);
```